# Regex - Java - migrate a JS regex pattern to input of Java Pattern class

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have following regex pattern working fine in Javascript :

**Pattern-**

```
/\<span\>(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\s*?(\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*?(?:am|pm))\s*?(?:<\/SPAN><BR\/?><SPAN>)?\s*?((\d[ -]*?){13,17})\s*?\<\/span\>/i
```

**String -**

```
<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>
```

But I am getting an error when passing same pattern string to `Pattern.compile()` function .

> Error is : Invalid escape sequence .

Here is what I tried :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\<span\>(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\s*?(\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*?(?:am|pm))\s*?(?:<\/SPAN><BR\/?><SPAN>)?\s*?((\d[ -]*?){13,17})\s*?\<\/span\>/i ");  

Matcher m = p.matcher("<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

Please suggest how can i correct this .

Thanks

**Edit**

I changed my code to following after knowing comments, but now I cannot match the pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "(?i)/\\<span\\>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?\\<\\/span\\>");

Matcher m = p.matcher("<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>");
boolean b = m.matches();

System.out.println("Do regex pattern matches : " + b);
```

Comment: Double the backslashes, and replace the `/` at the start with `(?i)` and remove `/i` at the end. The rest is up to you to check. And avoid escaping `/` - it is not a special regex metacharacter.

Comment: use \\ instead of \. Like `\\d` instead of `\d`.

Comment: *but now I cannot match the pattern* - Because there is `/` after `(?i)`. Do not escape  `/`, `<` and `>`.

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew can you please tell from where i can learn more on this  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE)** field option to make your regex case insensitive instead of using `(?i)` flag in your regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "\\<span\\>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?\\<\\/span\\>",
Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher m = p.matcher("<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>");

System.out.println("Do regex pattern matches : " + m.matches());
```

**Note:**

And also as mentioned in comments in Java you don't need to wrap your regex between slaches `/`, you need to update your regex string and remove the leading `/` from it and it will work as expected.

This is  [a working **Demo**](http://ideone.com/HxJOYD).

Comment: its not able to match either ways .

Comment: @Softxide You will need to update your regex string and remove the leading `/`, see my Edit.

Answer (score 1):

This one works. The only change derived from your edit was to remove the slash at the beginning. This was a simple JavaScript artifact.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                "(?i)\\<span\\>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?\\<\\/span\\>");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>");
boolean b = m.matches();
        System.out.println("Do regex pattern matches : " + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the first `/` character and use `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`.
For example:

```
String regex = "\\<span\\>(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*?(?:am|pm))\\s*?(?:<\\/SPAN><BR\\/?><SPAN>)?\\s*?((\\d[ -]*?){13,17})\\s*?\\<\\/span\\>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher m = p.matcher("<SPAN>06-24-2015  11:28AM  0250 01 90775 05342</SPAN>");
boolean b = m.matches();
System.out.println("result: "  + b);
```

Output:

```
result: true
```